# how to use variables of another class in the another logger class

Tags: android, json, logging

I have a **android application** which contain various **android library modules** which specify the activities/events performed by the application.Now i need to  build a **eventlog android library** which is used to log various **events** that occurs in the application like **login,logout** etc.

```
  public void Loginlog(int elapsedMs, String UserId, int   failedPasscodeAttempts, int successfulattempts) {
    createJson(TAG, "elapsedMs: "  + getTimeString(elapsedMs) + " UserId : " + UserId +  "failedattempts : " + failedPasscodeAttempts +  "Successfulattempts : "  +successfulattempts +  " attempts: " + totalattempts);
}
```

The variables **failedattempts,successfulattempts, attempts** etc are used in another login class in **different android module**.So is this a correct way to use variables from different class.

So how can i do please give some suggestion.

Comment: use shared pref to store variable or use interfaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can make static variable

create new class like this

```
public class Utils
{
   public static String DATA="NILU";
}
```

when you want to use that data use like this way

```
String str = Utils.DATA;
Utils.DATA = "NEW DATA";
```

> you can store values in [**`SharedPreferences`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Interface for accessing and modifying preference data returned by getSharedPreferences(String, int). For any particular set of preferences, there is a single instance of this class that all clients share.

Comment: we need to create both Json and StringtoJson class then later we can extend in any class ryt?